# DDoSを予告されたときに、すぐにできる緩和策はありますか？

Tags: network, security

自らの運営するサービスに対するDDoS攻撃を予告された場合、突然攻撃されることと比較して良い点はありますか？
例えば、「1時間後に攻撃する」と予告された場合、1時間でできるなんらかの緩和策はあるのでしょうか。
また、30日後の攻撃を予告された場合はどうでしょうか。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

サービスの規模にもよりますが、1時間あれば、

1. [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/ddos/)や[Microsoft Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/ja-jp/services/ddos-protection/)が提供するDDoS Protectionを導入できるでしょう。
2. [Akamai](https://www.akamai.com/jp/ja/contact-us/stop-ddos-attacks.jsp)やCloudflareにはDDoSの攻撃中に使える緊急サポートがあります。予告されただけでは対象になるか不明ですが、連絡を取ってみるのはアリです。
3. AWSなどスケールが容易な環境であれば、サーバ側のリソースを一時的に増強することも可能です。そうでない環境でも、30日あればいくらかの増強はできるのではないかな、と思います。

とはいえ、実際のDDoSの予告には脅しだけのものも多いですし、攻撃の規模は始まってからでないとわからないところがあります。